# How to Gif movie player pause at the first activity open

Tags: android, gif, movieplayer

I have implemented Gif movie player using https://github.com/sbakhtiarov/gif-movie-view, it's working good but I want pause Gif image when first start activity, that means first open activity, I tried **gif1.setPaused(true);** but it's not working so how can i solve it? Please guys help to solve it!!!

Answer (score 1):

I solve it using onDraw method, Just change

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //for infinitive time animate
        /*if (mMovie != null) {
            if (!mPaused) {
                updateAnimationTime();
                drawMovieFrame(canvas);
                invalidateView();
            } else {
                drawMovieFrame(canvas);
            }
        }*/

        //for one time animate
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) {
            mMovieStart = (int) now;
        }

        if (mMovie != null) {
            if (!mPaused) {
                int relTime = (int) (now - mMovieStart);

                if (relTime > mMovie.duration()) {
                    relTime = mMovie.duration();
                }

                mMovie.setTime(relTime);
                mMovie.draw(canvas,
                        getWidth() / 2 - mMovie.width() / 2,
                        getHeight() / 2 - mMovie.height() / 2);

                if (relTime < mMovie.duration()) {
                    invalidate();
                }
            } else {
                drawMovieFrame(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
```

And put in MainActivity

```
 gif1.setMovieResource(R.drawable.earth_tilt_animation);
        gif1.setPaused(!gif1.isPaused());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gif.setPaused(!gif.isPaused());
```

Because there is no code in library for **gif1.setPaused(true);**

Just check in ***GifMovieView.java***

```
public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
    this.mPaused = paused;

    /**
     * Calculate new movie start time, so that it resumes from the same
     * frame.
     */
    if (!paused) {
        mMovieStart = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mCurrentAnimationTime;
    }

    invalidate();
}
```

Try to make one function in ***GifMovieView.java***

```
public void stop() {    
    mMovie.stop;
    invalidate();
}
```

I m not sure it works but hope it will work.

Comment: Any another idea about How to stop player at the starting?

Comment: It like `setPaused` method is for restart gif not for stop.. wait i will see if anything i got !!

Comment: mMovieStart not contain stop method, Please have you another idea?

Comment: I have no idea now but if i got something then i  will update here

Comment: Try `mMovie.stop;` Instead of  `mMovieStart.stop;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113098/discussion-between-komal-and-chirag-ghori).